# How to implement repository in clean architecture

Tags: clean-architecture

I need to rewrite my project due to many underlying issues causing errors and I started following clean architecture by Uncle Bob (I read the book).

I created my `domain`, `infrastructure`, `application` and `interface-adapters`. In my domain directory I have an entity called `TreatmentPlan` containing all the business logic. I also define `ITreatmentPlanRepository` which defines my base methods of accessing data.

This is my `TreatmentPlan` entity

```
// TreatmentPlan.ts
interface TreatmentPlan {
    id?: number
    physicianId: number
    patientId: number
    startDate: Date | string
    endDate: Date | string
    endReason: string
    status: TreatmentPlanStatus
    diagnosisId: number
    diagnosisDate: Date | string
    initiationFormId: number
    activeSubstanceId: number
    activeSubstanceDosageId: number
    countryId: number
}


// TreatmentPlanRepository.ts
import { TreatmentPlan } from './entities/treatment-plan'

export interface AbstractTreatmentPlanRepository {
  listTreatmentPlans(): Promise<TreatmentPlan[] | []>

  getTreatmentPlan(id: string): Promise<TreatmentPlan[] | null>

  createTreatmentPlan(data: any): Promise<TreatmentPlan>

  updateTreatmentPlan(id: string, item: any): Promise<number>

  deleteTreatmentPlan(id: string, force?: boolean): Promise<number>
}
```

In my `application` directory I define my `usecases` eg. `CreateNewTreatmentPlanUseCase`. I know I want to use `Sequelize ORM` for database. I inject `AbstractTreatmentPlanRepository` to `CreateNewTreatmentPlanUseCase`.

In my `infrastructure` I have `sequelize` directory defining all the models and connection.

But I cannot figure out which layer I need to create my `SequelizeTreatmentPlanRepository`. Some say it needs to be in the `interface adapters` and some say it needs to be in the `application` layer. I would put that into the `infrastructure` directory but I cannot import anything from domain since this is the most inner layer of the structure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Some ORMs, including Sequelize (also EF in .NET) are 'Repository' implementations in the way they decouple common operations such as simple database CRUD and many queries from the application, exposing an entirely a database-agnostic interface which generally doesn't need further wrapping for ordinary use-cases. The people who built Sequelize/EF already hide that implementation detail.  Of course, it has limitations and for more advanced cases you may still need to write your own database logic, otherwise be careful that your repositories don't just become simple "pass-through" wrappers.

Comment: >  I would put that into the infrastructure directory but I cannot import anything from domain since this is the most inner layer of the structure.

Why can't you import the interface from the domain into the infrastructure? My understanding was the rule was imports can go outwards on the diagram, not inwards.

Comment: Since the domain doesn't have any UI of it's own, surely it must export /something/ or it would be completely useless.